# Extract values from data frame by subsetting based on current date and previous date

Tags: r, subset

I have the following data set which describes total training hours completed each week, with reference to the date the week ended on. Weeks are from Monday - Sunday and so `WeekEnding` dates are 7 days apart.

```
df<- structure(list(WeekEnding = c("2020-03-08", "2020-03-15", "2020-03-22", 
"2020-03-29", "2020-04-05", "2020-04-12", "2020-04-19", "2020-04-26"
), TotalTraining.hrs = c(14.119574637, 15.560762437, 14.160377084, 
16.968056203, 14.617250934, 10.865982397, 14.619121779, 13.135129677
)), row.names = c(NA, 8L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

This data will be updated every week. I would like to be able compare the total training hrs for the most recent week to the previous week. I can easily get the total training hours for the most recent week (i.e. the max week).

```
df$TotalTraining.hrs[df$WeekEnding == max(df$WeekEnding)]
[1] 13.13513
```

And I can manually enter the date to get the previous week

```
> df$TotalTraining.hrs[df$WeekEnding == "2020-04-19"]
[1] 14.61912
```

However as the data will be updated regularly, I would like to be able to reference the previous week off of the most recent week without having to manually enter the date.

```
> df$TotalTraining.hrs[df$WeekEnding == (max(df$WeekEnding)- 7)]
Error in max(df$WeekEnding) - 7 : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Is there a solution to this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is already ordered you can select the last two rows and subtract using `diff`.

```
diff(tail(df, 2)$TotalTraining.hrs)
#[1] -1.483992
```

If it is not ordered, you can order them first

```
df$WeekEnding <- as.Date(df$WeekEnding)
df <- df[order(df$WeekEnding),]
```

---

To calculate percentage change we can do :

```
x <- tail(f, 2)$TotalTraining.hrs
diff(x)/x[1] * 100
#[1] -10.15103
```

Comment: What if I wanted to calculate percentage change from previous week ? i.e. ((Current week total  - Previous week total) / Previous week total) *100)

Answer (score 1):

If ordered, the last one is

```
 df[length(df),]
```

and the previous

```
 df[length(df)-1,]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `which.max`, which indicates the **index** of the `max` value and subtract `1` off it:

```
diff <- df$TotalTraining.hrs[df$WeekEnding == max(df$WeekEnding)] - df$TotalTraining.hrs[which.max(df$WeekEnding) -1]
```

Result:

```
diff
[1] -1.483992
```

(This solution requires that `df`be ordered by `WeekEnding`.)